# jQuery Image VAMP (drag and resize)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create what I think should be pretty simple.. I have a static fixed div with a background image, and I want to drag and resize other images on top of it.

What I have doesn't appear to be working at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".image").resizable({aspectRatio:true}).parent().draggable();
});
</script>
<style>
#container {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image:url('background.png');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<img class="image" src="example.png">
<img class="image" src="example1.png">
<img class="image" src="example2.png">

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/DmUu4/

Comment: @Manish The only difference I see is that you changed the UI version, and that you added class="ui-widget-content" to the container. Why would this be working in jFiddle but not locally? What else am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting a blank page locally?

Comment: @Manish Locally in Firefox the images are draggable, but not resizable. In Chrome the example images don't show up at all. However both work fine in JSFiddle...

Comment: Use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />` as given on page http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ will wok in firefox now. In chrome images are getting shrink that's why they are invisible try `.image{width:200px;height:200px;}` in your css

Comment: @Manish That did it! Thank you. If you would like to post this as an answer I will mark the question completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/
themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

as given on page  http://jqueryui.com/resizable will wok in firefox now.

In chrome images are getting shrink that's why they are invisible try

```
.image{width:200px;height:200px;}
```

in your css